# ie8 weirdness: Link jumps to top of the page on mouse over: What's going on?

Tags: html, bugs, internet-explorer-8

So the fourth link in the right column (Board of Trustees Meeting Link) of the [website](http://www.mfrl.org/index.php) I'm working is exhibiting some REALLY weird behavior. But only in IE8. When you mouse over it the page scrolls to the top of the page, or sometimes goes blank entirely for a few seconds. 
Any idea what's going on here? I've tried turning compatibility mode on and off, using strict/transitional 4.01 html doctype, and html 5 doctype declartions. The link is no different from other links on the page (programmatically). I've examined the code six ways to sunday and I can't figure out what's causing this. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: Solved due to other changes in the page. Still don't know what was actually causing this problem, but it's no longer being exhibited by the webpage. /:

Comment: That is weird. Is there any JavaScript associated with any of the content in that DIV?

Comment: Not with that div. There is some with the first div in the left column, but it shouldn't (and as far as I can tell doesn't) affect anything else.

Comment: Disabled javascript and see if you still get the same problem.  That will at least help you narrow it down.

Comment: I'm not sure ... If I take out the jQuery from the web page it doesn't do it, but if I disable javascript from w/in IE8 the bit of jQuery stops working as expected, but the weirdness continues.

Answer (score 2):

To debug this, open the page in IE8. Hit F12 to open developer tools. Click on the "Script" tab. Press the "break all" button. Hover over the link. The debugger breaks in the function called.

I can't tell you why it's doing it, but I imagine you can figure out why that script is being called.